# How to automate linux cut command using bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Let suppose I have a text file having `4` column and I have to cut every single column and save it into another text file. Manually I can do this by the following Linux command but I want to automate this process using bash script. Can someone help me with this

```
cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f1 > output1.txt

cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f2 > output2.txt

cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f3 > output3.txt

cut  textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f4 > output4.txt
```

Textfile.txt

"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"
"text1":"text2":"text3":"text4"

`col 1 should store in output1.txt
"text1"
"text1"
"text1"
"text1"
"text1"
"text1"
"text1"
"text1"
"text1"
col 2 should store in output2.txt
"text2"
"text2"
"text2"
"text2"
"text2"
"text2"
"text2"
"text2"
"text2"
col 3 should store in output3.txt
"text3"
"text3"
"text3"
"text3"
"text3"
"text3"
"text3"
"text3"
"text3"
col 4 should store in output4.txt
"text4"
"text4"
"text4"
"text4"
"text4"
"text4"
"text4"
"text4"
"text4"`

Comment: What do you expect `grep textfile.txt` to do?

Comment: I want to cat a textfile and cut every column -f1,-f2,-f3,-f4 into separate output file.

Comment: Yes you said that but then your code does `grep textfile.txt` which will hang waiting for input so the question is - did you mean `cat` when you wrote `grep` or did you mean `grep "something" textfile.txt` and, if so, what is that "something"? Please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: cat textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f1 > output1.txt
cat textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f2 > output2.txt
cat textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f3 > output3.txt
cat textfile.txt | cut -d ":" -f4 > output4.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each `grep textfile.txt` in your question was intended to be `cat textfile.txt` (and if so google UUOC), all you need is:

```
awk -F':' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i > ("output"i".txt")}' textfile.txt
```